# how to keep initial cell color, while code is hilighting active row

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code for workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'toggles worksheet colors
'code will remove all color
'and color active row and column

  If ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
     Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
  Else
     Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
     ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End If
End Sub
```

and works good. but if a row has an initial color, it will be removed. let me know how 
active row will be highlighted and by changing the row, will get its initial color?

Comment: By using a hidden sheet and storing/retrieving the formats of that row in that

Comment: Or wait... I think I created an Add-In for this.. Let me search for the code... :P

Answer (score 1):

Damn, I couldn't find the Add-In but I recreated the code for you. Please note that this is not thoroughly tested. In whatever small tests that I did, it works...

**Logic**:

1. Create a hidden sheet.
2. Store the current cell's formats in row 1 of that hidden sheet
3. Store the currently selected row number in active sheet to cell `A2` of the hidden sheet
4. when you move to a different row then retrieve the last row number and restore it.

**Code**:

In thisWorkbook code area

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Delete the Temp sheet we created i.e if we created
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("MyHiddenSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    '~~> ReCreate the Sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    '~~> i am using a normal name. Chnage as applicable
    ws.Name = "MyHiddenSheet"
    '~~> Hide the sheet
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

In relevant sheet code area. I am using `Sheet1` as an example

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    '~~> Don't do anything if multiple cells are selected
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Set our relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyHiddenSheet")

    '~~> Get the row number of the last row we had selected earlier
    '~~> For obvious reasons, this will be empty for the first use.
    If Len(Trim(ws.Cells(2, 1).Value)) <> 0 Then
        '~~> If user has moved to another row then
        '~~> Restor the old row
        If Target.Row <> Val(ws.Cells(2, 1).Value) Then
            ws.Rows(1).Copy
            Rows(ws.Cells(2, 1).Value).PasteSpecial xlFormats
        End If
    End If

    '~~> Copy the current row's format to the hidden sheet
    Rows(Target.Row).Copy
    ws.Rows(1).PasteSpecial xlFormats
    '~~> Store the current rows value in cell A2
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Value = Target.Row

    '~~> Highlight the current row in a shade of blue.
    '~~> Chnage as applicable
    With Rows(Target.Row).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Rows(Target.Row).Select
    End With

    '~~> Remove the `Ants` which appear after you do a copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**Screenshots**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate approach which makes use of the fact that Excel always "overlays" Conditional Formatting on top of whatever formatting is already on the sheet.

Define a worksheet-level name "ROWNUM" and assign a value of 0.

Add a conditional format using the formula `=(ROW()=ROWNUM)` and add whatever formatting you want to use for row highlighting.

Your SelectionChange sub is then just:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Me.Names("ROWNUM").RefersToR1C1 = "=" & Target.Cells(1).Row
End Sub
```