# Method of Intersect of Object Global Failed: Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I had save a code in my worksheet and in the same worksheet I had hyperlink some cell but whenever I click on the hyperlink it gives following error.

`Error 1004: Method of intersect of object global failed`.

This is the code which I have in my worksheet:

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A2:O601")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A2:O601").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A"), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "O")).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ActiveCell` use `Target`

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:O601")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A2:O601").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "O")).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also write your code as

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:O601")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A2:O601").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        Dim rw As Long

        rw = Target.Row

        Range("A" & rw & ":O" & rw).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End If
End Sub
```

**TIP**: I think you are trying to create a row highlighter. If yes, then you may want to see my answer in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929769/how-to-keep-initial-cell-color-while-code-is-hilighting-active-row) post which explains with screenshots.